# Como integrar Objective-C e Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Estou fazendo um projeto em Swift e gostaria de usar alguns arquivos em Objective-C. É possível fazer isso?

No caso eu instalei usando o [Cocoa Pods](http://cocoapods.org/), não sei se isso influencia em algo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Usando classes em *Objective-C* no *Swift*

### Criando um *Bridging Header*

#### Quando você arrasta os arquivos para o projeto

Ao arrastar um `.m` O *Xcode* <del>vai</del> muito provavelmente vai te mostrar essa janela:
[image]

Basta responder **Sim** e o *Xcode* faz toda a magia para você!

#### Quando você usa *Cocoa Pods*

(ou quando o Xcode não faz a mágica dele)

- Crie um *Header* de *Objetive-C* fazendo <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> e selecionado *Objective-C Header*.
- Vá nas configurações do projeto > *Build Settings* > *Swift Compiler - Code Generation* e coloque o nome do seu Header.

Você pode fazer como nessa imagem:
[image: Adding]
Mas não se esqueça de trocar o começo do *Path* para `$(SRCROOT)` para garantir que o código compilará em outras máquinas.

### Importando classes *Objective-C*

Basta incluir no seu *Bridging Header* os imports no padrão *Objective-C*, por exemplo, para importar a classe `XMLDictionary` use

```
#import "XMLDictionary.h"
```

## Chamando métodos de *Objetive-C* em *Swift*

Agora basta usar os métodos, não é necessário importar nada nas suas classes *Swift*, é simples assim!

**Miscelânea:**

- Mais informações sobre esse assunto e fonte das imagens [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift) (em inglês).
- É interessante seguir a convenção de nome do Xcode e nomear seu *bridging header* de `Meu_Projeto-Bridging-Header.h` onde seu projeto se chama `Meu Projeto` (troque espaços por `_`.

Para fins de completude aí vai a resposta da pergunta espelho:

## Usando classe *Swift* em *Objective-C*

Usar classes *Swift* em *Objective-C* é ainda mais simples!

### Se sua classe herda de `NSObject`

Basta importar `"MeuProjeto-Swift.h"` no `Objective-C`

#### Se esse arquivo não aparecer

- Em *Build Settings* > *Packaging*:

  - Marque *Defines Module* como **Yes**
  - Garanta que *Product Module Name* possui **apenas** caracteres alfa-numéricos
- Em *Bulid Settings* > *Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language - Modules*:

  - Marque *Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)* como **Yes**

**Importante**: é normal esse arquivo não ser listado, você deve conseguir importá-lo mesmo assim.

### Se sua classe **não** herda de `NSObject`

- Coloque o prefixo `@objc` antes de `class` na sua classe *Swift*
- Crie um método de classe para ser seu construtor
  Exemplo:

import Foundation

```
@objc class ObjetoSwiftPuro {

    var nome: String
    init(nome: String) {
        self.nome = nome
    }

    // Método de classe para retornar instância nova
    class func novaInstanciaNomeada(nome: String) -> ObjetoSwiftPuro {
        return ObjetoSwiftPuro(nome: nome)
    }
}
```

**Full disclaimer:** a parte de usar Swift em Objective-C foi inspirada na resposta de **@Logan** com participação de **@TomášLinhart**.

Comment: Segunda vez que vejo você postar uma pergunta e logo de imediato responder. Qual o motivo?

Comment: Compartilhar conhecimento no estilo Q&A! Quando eu percebo que colegas desenvolvedores vem me perguntar dúvidas recorrentes em posto a pergunta e resposta no SO. De uma olhada [aqui](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). Eu não ganho pontos por marcar minha própria resposta como certa, faço isso para compartilhar conhecimento, outras respostas são bem-vindas e se forem melhores que a minha não pensarei duas vezes antes marca-las como "Resposta certa". :)

Comment: Para quem está dando downvote, pode explicar? Esta solução está funcionando perfeitamente para mim.

Comment: Uma dica é usar `$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h` quando for adicionar no Swift Compiler - Code Generation, assim você garante que o Xcode sempre vá buscar da pasta do projeto e assim evitando problemas no caso de ter mais de uma pessoa trabalhando no projeto :)