# Erro ao usar STTwitter e Swifter

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, twitter-api

Estou tentando usar uma das duas bibliotecas STTwitter ou Swifter no meu projeto mas sempre da erro.

No caso da STTwitter o erro é na chamada do metodo `getUserTimelineWithScreenName:(NSString *)screenName successBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *statuses))successBlock errorBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))errorBlock;`

O que acontece é que o Xcode fica reclamando `"Missing argument for parameter 'sinceID' in call"` só que não tem esse parâmetro no método..

Segue o codigo:

```
    twitter.verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock({ (username: String!) -> Void in

            twitter.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(
                screenName: "gregoryfm",
                successBlock: { (status: Array!) -> Void in
                    println("deu certo")
                },
                errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    println("verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock error:  \(error.description)")
                })
        },
        errorBlock: { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
            println("verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock error:  \(error.description)")
        })
```

E ao testar a Swifter quando importo ela no projeto dá erro de compilação na classe String+Swifter.

Estou usando o Xcode 6.1.1 com o iOS SDK 8.1
Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: Essa biblioteca é de Objective-C. Dê uma olhada de como integrar Objective-C com Swift: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47238/como-integrar-objective-c-e-swift

Comment: O problema não é na integração. Eu já criei o arquivo de Bridging Header fiz a importação. No caso da lib STTwitter o problema esta só na chamada desse metodo que citei, pois uso outro metodo antes para passar as duas chaves e funciona normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Em Swift não se deve colocar o `label` do primeiro parâmetro como vemos na [documentação](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_299)

Isso ocorre para a leitura ficar igual a do Objective-C. Como já há o `screenName` no nome do método ele não deve ser especificado.

Basta remover `screenName:` e seu código funcionará!

Por exemplo, o código Objective-C

```
[twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName: name successBlock: successBlock errorBlock: errorBlock];
```

Em Swift fica:

```
twitter.getUserTimelineWithScreenName(name, successBlock: successBlock, errorBlock: errorBlock)
```

entendeu?

Veja mais [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24815869/2305521) excelente resposta do SO (em inglês).